# Long string in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a report CR. In my report I check if the record exist more than once in the table, if it's the case i concatenate the Column "Other" of these records and I display just one line in my report with the concatenated value. However, the concatenated string could be very long and I think that StringVar has a limit of 254 characters. Even if i think to use more than one StringVar i can not guess how many variables should i declare since i can not guess every time how many duplicated records i could have. Any help please?

Thanks very much !
Walloud

Comment: I'm not sure what the limit on a `StringVar` is, but it is more than 254.  I tested 1025 characters (just over 1k) in Crystal 9 and XI with no trouble.  Have you tried putting it all into one variable and seeing what happens?

Comment: Max string length in CR is 65,534 characters.